# How to print multiple lists in a single line in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
print( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in (l1, l2, l3)) )
```

I'm using the above command to print output from my 3 lists l1, l2 and l3. But the output which is printed is in the form of [1,22,34], [4,56,34,23],[13,21] instead I want it to be like 1,22,34,4,56,34,23,13,21

I want them all to be in a single line separated by comma and not enclosed in brackets. Any idea how to implement it in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

You could conctinate the lists before joining the items:

```
print(", ".join(str(i) for i in l1 + l2 + l3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = []
out.extend(l1)
out.extend(l2)
out.extend(l3)
print ','.join(out)
```